# What was the role of Midnapore town in present day West Bengal of India in the armed struggle for freedom in Bengal province of British India?

Tags: india, british-empire

The famous extremist freedom fighter [Khudiram Bose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Khudiram_Bose) from Midnapore who was the first extremist freedom fighter in British India to be hanged is quite famous.

Who were all the famous extremist freedom fighters from Midnapore? Was there any family whose every member went on to become extremist freedom fighter? What was the net impact on freedom fight in Bengal from the extremist freedom fighters of Midnapore? Was there any members from Midnapore who joined [Netaji's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subhas_Chandra_Bose) [Azad Hind Fauj](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Azad_Hind)?

Comment: You might find [Militant Nationalism in India Midnapore](https://www.jstor.org/stable/44147890?read-now=1&refreqid=excelsior%3A3b3a6cbc048923d24723789bf327dc5e&seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents) by Shyamapada Bhowmik of interest.

Comment: You might get better answers if you used less loaded terms (remember the saying about "One man's freedom fighter,,,:), and perhaps specified the time period you're interested in.

Answer (score -1):

Midnapore has a rich history in the struggle for freedom.

One of the famous freedom fighters from Midnapore is [Matangini Hazra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matangini_Hazra). In the time of the [Quit India Movement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quit_India_Movement) she with Ramacandra Bera, lead thousands of people to taking over the Tamluk police station and Court with the purpose of overthrowing the British government in the district and establishing an independent Indian state. As she stepped forward the police open fire, she was repeatedly shot but she kept chanting "[Vande Mataram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vande_Mataram)" and step forward.

She died with the tri-color  flag held high and still flying